# ¿Cómo transformar filas a columnas en SQL o tratando el resultado en PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Os traslado mi pregunta.
Tengo la siguiente sentencia en SQL:

```
SELECT a.id as albumid, a.name as album, so.NAME AS name, YEAR(c.DATE) AS ddate, COUNT(s.idsong) AS num_tocadas
FROM setlists s, concerts c, songs so, albums a
WHERE s.idconcert = c.id
AND s.idsong = so.id
AND so.idalbum = a.id
AND a.id = 1
AND s.validate = 1
AND c.validate = 1
AND c.idartist = 1
GROUP BY idalbum, album, NAME, ddate
ORDER BY NAME, ddate ASC
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: Resultado de la sentencia]

Me gustaría obtener estos resultados añadiendo años en los cuales no se han tocado las canciones (desde 1995 hasta el año actual) pero cambiando las filas por las columnas de la siguiente manera:

[image: Resultado esperado]

¿Existe alguna manera de obtener estos datos de esta manera?
Estoy intentando sacarlo directamente por SQL pero si se pudiera realizar en código (php) me valdría igual. Por más que busco no encuentro la solución.

Muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: En SQL ni idea, pero en PHP podrías recorrer el resultado e ir rellenando un array multidimensional con las claves albumid, album y name, e irle agregando los años que van saliendo junto con sus valores.  Y luego recorres los años que quieres mostrar en esa nueva tabla y compruebas, en cada año, si ese nuevo array multidimensional contiene datos para ellos recorriendolo internamente (anidado) para comprobar todas las claves.  Inténtalo, y si no te sale pon en la pregunta hasta donde has llegado, el error que te da y miramos de ayudarte partiendo de alli.

Comment: Me está siendo totalmente imposible hasta tirando por el php, si veo la luz, voy escribiéndolo por aquí, gracias por la pista @masterguru

Comment: Pon el resultado de la consulta en modo texto en la pregunta, no como imagen, para que pueda hacer mis pruebas e intentar mostrarte una respuesta. Las imágenes no permiten la copia de los datos e impiden que puedas recibir mejores ayudas. En el pie de la pregunta tienes el enlace [edit] que te permite modificarla las veces que sea necesario.  Mi comentario no era del todo acertado, hay más miga de lo que he comentado antes y quiero jugar con los datos para verificarlo.